# Intercepting Processor State on Segfault

Tags: c++, debugging, x86, segmentation-fault, jit

I am working on a program which analyzes PowerPC code and generates LLVM code for it. As my analysis of branch points/subroutine adresses the code may be incomplete (for example, if the code does something very weird with function pointers) I plan to have a fallback mechanism set up like so:

1. Generated subroutine attempts to branch to address from original program, which will be an unmapped/unexecutable page (depending on host architecture capabilities).
2. A segmentation fault results.
3. Segmentation fault handler identifies what happens, saves the address for full analysis the next time the program is started, then performs a quick and dirty analysis and uses LLVM's JIT capacity to generate executable code for the new branch target.
4. Processor state at the time of the branch is restored, except directed towards the newly generated code.

The problem is I cannot figure out how to obtain the processor state at the segmentation fault. I'm fairly certain there is a way, as GDB does this all the time.

Although the code is cross-platform, I'm focusing on implementing it on x86 OSX/Posix right now.

Comment: The [i386 Programmers' Reference](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2012/readings/i386.pdf) might probably help you investigating the the stackframe of *SegFault* (what info it contains, etc.). All the other data are simply in the registers/TSS/etc. Buffer them somewhere. **PS: For such stuff you can't get away without ASM**

Comment: The problem is getting it to work when an operating system intercepts the segmentation fault. All of that information will be in kernel space. I am aware how to do it if I can intercept the interrupt in my own code, but that is not possible in user space.